# Switch if empty in Scala

Tags: scala

I´m starting with Scala and using the stream I would like to know if there anything like switchIfEmpty for the pipeline.

Here what I had with RxJava

```
@Test
public void testSwitc() {
    Observable.just(new ArrayList<>())
              .switchIfEmpty(Observable.just(Arrays.asList(1))
              .subscribe(System.out::println);

}
```

And this is what I want to attempt

```
        def distinctList(prevResult: List[Char], currentItem:  List[Char]): List[Char] = {
           currentItem.toStream
            .filter(currentChar => !prevResult.contains(currentChar))
            .map(c=> prevResult++currentItem)
            .switchIfEmpty(prevResult)--> how can I return a default value
```

}

I want that In case that the filter does not emit anything return a default value.

Comment: Could you explain desired behavior?

Comment: I update my question, let me know if it´s clear enough

Comment: what about `(prevResult++currentItem).distinct`?

Comment: Thanks, that will works, but anyway I was wondering if that operator exist in Scala as in RxJava

Answer (score 2):

You can use `foldLeft` to fold your input list of stream and then perform a pattern matching against the folded result as shown below:

```
def distinctList(prevResult: List[Char], currentItem:  List[Char]): List[Char] = {
  currentItem.toStream
    .foldLeft(prevResult){ case (result, currentChar) =>
      prevResult ++ result.filter(r => !result.contains(currentChar))
    } match {
      case Nil => "how can I return a default value".toList
      case x => x
    }
}
```

Comment: That´s the thing, all that code would be great to have it in an operator, switchIfEmpty(defaultValue), maybe in future versions :)

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using `Observable.just` you can use `Option[A+]` in Scala which is built inside the language, `Option` has an innate function that allows you to get the value of your calculation or a default value via `getOrElse` which takes in your default value which should be the same type as your `Option`'s current type

By the way, your function returns a `Stream[List[Char]]` you should fix it to get your desired return value.

Comment: What is the different between use currentItem.toStream and Option?, Can you provide an example please

Comment: You can think of Option as a container that provides for you a method to handle Null values, Stream is a form of Data Structure Container that allows you to create a Sequence but the difference between a list and a stream is that a stream is lazily evaluated or in mathematics "non-strict" hence it is just there left uncalculated until you ask for it to be calculated via calling it.